# Proving a Series Semi-Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I'm currently practicing problems for an upcoming test, but I'm not sure how to prove this series semi-convergence. This is the series:

$$\sum U_n=\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\ln n}$$

My professor puts as a hint: $\ln n\le n$ for $n$ great enough, but I'm not sure on the correct way of stating this. If it was divergent, I would simply state that we know $\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent and $\frac{1}{\ln n}\ge \frac{1}{n}$ so $\frac{1}{\ln n}$ is divergent by comparison but I'm not sure the same works for semi-convergence. Would this comparison be valid in the case of a semi-convergent series?

Comment: Are you familiar with the alternating series test? Much of the intuition you are describing derives from sums of positive numbers where there is no possibility of 'cancellation.'

Comment: My professor provided a theorem stating a series convergence if: 1) The series is alternating 2) The limit of Un as n approaches infinity is 0 3) (Un) is decreasing. Is this it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming by semi you mean conditionally convergent.

Apply the alternating series test to show that $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}$ is convergent.

That is for $n>1$, show that $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ is positive, decreasing and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}=0.$

Comment: You are correct, my professor said that in some texts it's also known as Conditionally Convergent. I should probably refer to it as that from now on. I initially thought of using the alternating series test, but I was trying to understand why he included that hint. However, this does answer my question so thank you very much!

Comment: That makes sense. I was unaware I could prove this like that so it's good to know for the future. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Dirichlet's criterion states that if $(a_n)$ is a sequence with bounded partial sums and $(b_n)$ is a sequence that decreases to $0$ then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n b_n} < +\infty$$
Here $a_n = (-1)^n%$ which has bounded partial sums (if $s_n = a_1 + \dots + a_n$ then $s_n = 0$ for even $n$ and $s_n = -1$ for odd $n$ hence it's bounded) and $b_n = \frac{1}{\ln n}$ which decreases to $0$. From Dirichlet's criterion
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n} < +\infty$$
To show that this series is semi-convergent notice that
$$\left| \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n} \right| = \frac{1}{\ln n}$$
and then your argument works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So is it valid to use the comparison 1/lnn ≥ 1/n for semi-convergence (conditionally convergent)? We were told that a series in the form (-1)^n/n^p is semi-convergent if 0<p≤1, but I'm not sure if my comparison argument also applies for these cases as I've only used it for convergent/divergent series.

Comment: $s_n =\color{red}-1$ for odd $n$;

Comment: @DanielGarcia Yes, your argument is correct to show that the series cannot converge absolutely. The alternating series criterion is actually a corollary of Dirichlet's criterion.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis It hadn't occurred to me that I could prove its conditional convergence by demonstrating that it is not absolutely convergent first. Now I know for the future. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielGarcia Always happy to help :)